# C program not taking user input

Tags: c

i am a beginner in C programming. I was learning about the user inputs. The following piece of code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        char grade;
        printf("Enter you grade: ");
        scanf("%c", &grade);
        printf("Your grade is %c.", grade);

        return 0;
     }
```

does what I intend it to do i.e.

- ask for the grade
- display the grade

But when I modify the code to the following :

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>

     int main()
    {
           int age;
           printf("Enter you age: ");
           scanf("%d", &age);  
           printf("You are %d years old.\n", age);

           printf("-----------------------------\n");
           double gpa;
           printf("Enter your GPA: ");
           scanf("%lf", &gpa);
           printf("Your GPA is %f. \n", gpa);

           printf("-----------------------------\n");
           char grade;
           printf("Enter you grade: ");
           scanf("%c", &grade);
           printf("Your grade is %c.", grade);

           return 0;
     }
```

it does the following:

- asks for the age
- displays the age
- asks for the gpa
- displays gpa
- asks for grade
- it doesnt display grade.

The output looks like:

> ```
> Enter you age: 45
> You are 45 years old.
> -----------------------------
> Enter your GPA: 4
> Your GPA is 4.000000. 
> -----------------------------
> Enter you grade: Your grade is 
> .
> ```

please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter your age, this is what is in the input buffer just before the `scanf(%d)` starts retrieving characters:

```
45<newline>
```

The `scan(%d)` skips any white space in the buffer (there isn't any), reads the `45`, but leaves the newline. Then when you enter your GPA, this is what is in the input buffer just before the `scanf(%lf)` starts retrieving characters:

```
<newline>4<newline>
```

The `scan(%lf)` skips any white space in the buffer (the newline), reads the `4`, but again leaves the newline. In other words, the leading newline doesn't matter if your next next `scanf` *also* skips whitespace such as moving from the first entry to the second.

But `scanf(%c)` does *not* skip white space. It simply reads the next character, which is a newline:

```
<newline>A<newline>
```

That's why tour period appears on the following line, it *has* read a character, but that character was the newline rather than the grade.

Section `7.21.6.2 The fscanf function`, in the ISO C11 standard, has this to say on the first step of processing a conversion specifier (my emphasis):

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, ***unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier.***

A quick fix would be to manually skip whitespace yourself, something like:

```
printf("Enter your grade: ");
scanf(" %c", &grade);
printf("Your grade is %c.", grade);
```

as per that same section of the standard:

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read.